# Renaming a file with the previous month instead of the current month

Tags: php, file, rename

Right now the file is being renamed with the current month (June), when it should be the previous month.  Can anyone suggest how I would alter this code for the desired output?  I tried F-1 but it didnt work, it said June 1 instead of the month before.

Code:

```
 rename       ("C:\Smurf_Reports\mssql\Monthly_Stats\monthly_mssql.csv", "C:\Smurf_Reports\mssql\Monthly_    Stats\old\monthly_mssql_" . date("m_Y") . ".csv");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `date()`, just simply subtract one month:

```
rename("C:\Smurf_Reports\mssql\Monthly_Stats\monthly_mssql.csv", "C:\Smurf_Reports\mssql\Monthly_Stats\old\monthly_mssql_" . date("m_Y", strtotime("-1 month")) . ".csv");
```

As of today, would rename the file to: `"C:\Smurf_Reports\mssql\Monthly_Stats\old\monthly_mssql_05_2013.csv`

Answer (score 0):

You want to tell the date function to use the previous month

```
rename       ("C:\Smurf_Reports\mssql\Monthly_Stats\monthly_mssql.csv", "C:\Smurf_Reports\mssql\Monthly_    Stats\old\monthly_mssql_" . date("m_Y",strtotime('-1 month')) . ".csv");
```